# Set Pivot Selection to another in SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, windows-phone, pivotviewer, pivotitem

I want to make a pivot navigating to item[0] when it was navigated from item[2] to item[1], from item[3] to item[2], etc.

Here is code:

```
int lastIndex = 0;
private void PageChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
            }
            if (MainPivot.SelectedIndex + 1 == lastIndex)
            {
                MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            lastIndex = MainPivot.SelectedIndex;
        }
```

And XAML:

```
    <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" SelectionChanged="PageChanged">
        <PivotItem Margin="0" Background="Red">

        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Margin="0" Background="#FF0017FF">

        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Margin="0" Background="Yellow">

        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Margin="0" Background="#FFE800FF">

        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

But UI doesn`t react to

```
MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

As I see, pivot will not set page until animation is over.

Is here another way to navigate to other PivotItem before navigation completed or event fires before navigation started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a small delay before setting index to zero.

```
    int lastIndex = 0;
private async void PageChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (MainPivot.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Do smth
                    break;
            }
            if (MainPivot.SelectedIndex + 1 == lastIndex)
            {
                await Task.Delay(50);
                MainPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            lastIndex = MainPivot.SelectedIndex;
        }
```

I have given  `await Task.Delay(50);` You can optimize this by reducing the delay time.

Comment: Nice idea, I was thinking about it. I`ll check it soon

Comment: await Task.Delay(5); is enough

Comment: I’m glad I was able to help :).